# why am I getting the deployment error?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web-applications, netbeans

As I try to deploy my web application from netbeans, I get the following error :

```
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Tomcat server started.
W:\UnderTest\NetbeansCurrent\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1033: 
Deployment error: Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized.
Set the correct username and password with the "manager-script" role in the 
Tomcat customizer in the Server Manager.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 14 seconds)
```

What is that ? Why am I getting this error ?

*Following is the snippet from* `tomcat-users.xml` :

```
    <tomcat-users>
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->

  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="suhail" password="suhail" roles="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

Following is the snapshot from netbeans server settings :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the `manager-script` in order to perform deployment operations.

So in you xml you should have something like

```
<user username="suhail" password="suhail" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

Comment: It is discouraged to apply both, manager-gui and manager-script, to the same user. See the documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html